# JavaFX "endless" pane

Tags: java, canvas, javafx, fxml

So I am trying to create a kind of paint/photoshop-like application application in JavaFX with a canvas and toolbar. What I want is for the canvas to be rather large or even endless, if possible. I want the user to be able to pan around over the canvas and zoom in and out, etc. My solution for this is to put the toolbars in a BorderPane and the canvas is a regular Pane (so not a JavaFX-Canvas) and then stack the BorderPane on top of the Pane in a StackPane. The problem that arises is when I want to make the Pane really large in size, this pushes the content of the BorderPane off-screen because they are both in same StackPane.

Here's the StackPane fxml:

```
<StackPane fx:controller="controller.MainController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">

  <Pane fx:id="aDrawPane">

  </Pane>
  <BorderPane fx:id="aBorderPane">
      <top>
          <VBox>
              <ToolBar fx:id="aToolBar" orientation="HORIZONTAL">
                  <HBox fx:id="umlBox">
                      <Button text="Create" fx:id="createBtn"/>
                      <Button text="Package" fx:id="packageBtn"/>
                      <Button text="Edge" fx:id="edgeBtn"/>
                      <Button text="Draw" fx:id="drawBtn"/>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox fx:id="utilBox">
                      <Button text="Select" fx:id="selectBtn"/>
                      <Button text="Move" fx:id="moveBtn"/>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox fx:id="undoBox">
                      <Button text="Delete" fx:id="deleteBtn"/>
                      <Button text="Undo" fx:id="undoBtn"/>
                      <Button text="Redo" fx:id="redoBtn"/>
                  </HBox>
                  <HBox fx:id="recognizeBox">
                      <Button text="Recognize" fx:id="recognizeBtn"/>
                  </HBox>
              </ToolBar>
          </VBox>
      </top>
      <bottom>
          <ToolBar>
              <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
              <VBox alignment="CENTER">
                  <Slider fx:id="zoomSlider" min="10"  max="200" value="100"/>
                  <Label text="Zoom"/>
              </VBox>
              <Pane HBox.hgrow="ALWAYS" />
          </ToolBar>
      </bottom>
  </BorderPane>
</StackPane>
```

That fxml is also actually put in tabs inside this fxml:

```
<VBox fx:controller="controller.TabController" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
<MenuBar fx:id="menuBar">
    <menus>
        <Menu text="File">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="New" onAction="#handleMenuActionNew"/>
                <MenuItem text="Open" onAction="#handleMenuActionLoad"/>
                <MenuItem text="Save" onAction="#handleMenuActionSave"/>
                <SeparatorMenuItem/>
                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="mouseMenuItem" text="Activate Mouse" onAction="#handleMenuActionMouse" selected="false"/>
                <SeparatorMenuItem/>
                <MenuItem text="Exit" onAction="#handleMenuActionExit"/>
            </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu text="Edit">
            <items>
                <MenuItem text="Copy"/>
                <MenuItem text="Cut"/>
                <MenuItem text="Paste"/>
            </items>
        </Menu>
        <Menu text="View">
            <items>
                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="umlMenuItem" text="UML" onAction="#handleMenuActionUML" selected="true"/>
                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="sketchesMenuItem" text="Sketches" onAction="#handleMenuActionSketches" selected="true"/>
                <CheckMenuItem fx:id="gridMenuItem" text="Grid" onAction="#handleMenuActionGrid" selected="true"/>
            </items>
        </Menu>
    </menus>
</MenuBar>
<TabPane fx:id="tabPane">

</TabPane>
<stylesheets>
    <URL value="@main.css" />
</stylesheets>
</VBox>
```

So the StackPane is put inside a tab which is inside the TabPane.
So what I want is the for the "aDrawPane" to be really large (or even with the feeling of it being endless) while the user is only focused on a small part of it to start with but able to pan and zoom around it. I want it to be "underneath" the toolbars.

I hope I have explained myself clearly. I'm looking for guidance on how to structure such an application with the JavaFX library and not how to implement the functionality of drawing/zooming/panning.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are over-complicating the issue quite a bit. First of all, the order of your panes is incorrect. The BorderPane lies "above" the Pane right now.

The BorderPane already has a "CENTER" that is meant to be used for your cases. Wrap your Pane is a ScrollPane and put it there.

Here is an example:

```
<?import javafx.geometry.Insets?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Button?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Label?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ScrollPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.Slider?>
<?import javafx.scene.control.ToolBar?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.HBox?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.Pane?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.VBox?>

<BorderPane fx:id="aBorderPane" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.60" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1">
    <top>
        <VBox>
            <ToolBar fx:id="aToolBar" orientation="HORIZONTAL">
                <HBox fx:id="umlBox">
                    <Button fx:id="createBtn" text="Create" />
                    <Button fx:id="packageBtn" text="Package" />
                    <Button fx:id="edgeBtn" text="Edge" />
                    <Button fx:id="drawBtn" text="Draw" />
                </HBox>
                <HBox fx:id="utilBox">
                    <Button fx:id="selectBtn" text="Select" />
                    <Button fx:id="moveBtn" text="Move" />
                </HBox>
                <HBox fx:id="undoBox">
                    <Button fx:id="deleteBtn" text="Delete" />
                    <Button fx:id="undoBtn" text="Undo" />
                    <Button fx:id="redoBtn" text="Redo" />
                </HBox>
                <HBox fx:id="recognizeBox">
                    <Button fx:id="recognizeBtn" text="Recognize" />
                </HBox>
            </ToolBar>
        </VBox>
    </top>
    <bottom>
         <VBox alignment="CENTER" fillWidth="false">
             <Slider fx:id="zoomSlider" max="200" min="10" value="100" />
             <Label text="Zoom" />
         <padding>
            <Insets top="8.0" />
         </padding>
         </VBox>
    </bottom>
    <center>
        <ScrollPane pannable="true" prefViewportHeight="400.0" prefViewportWidth="400.0" BorderPane.alignment="CENTER">
            <content>
                <Pane fx:id="aDrawPane" maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="8000.0" prefWidth="8000.0">
                </Pane>
            </content>
        </ScrollPane>
    </center>
   <padding>
      <Insets bottom="8.0" left="8.0" right="8.0" top="8.0" />
   </padding>
</BorderPane>
```

In this example the pane will grow with its children, meaning as you draw/position elements in it the Pane will grow/shrink.

### Virtual Canvas

If you want to simulate an infinite empty space, where the user can scroll and move around even no item s are drawn yet, you have to implement it programatically, FXML alone is too limited.

Basically you'd create an AnchorPane with the drawPane inside a Group, and 2 ScrollBars. Then write code to translate the drawPane in X/Y-directions.

```
AnchorPane
   -> Group (setManaged(false))
      '-> drawPane
   -> vertical ScrollBar
   -> horizontal ScrollBar
```

The group will automatically resize to encompass all of its children. It needs to be "unmanaged" so that its parent (the AnchorPane) does not resize itself so that you can put it into the rest of your GUI, without pushing it around, effectively creating the viewport into your canvas.
Whit this layout, the Group becomes the infinite, virtual canvas and the drawPane becomes some sort of logical boundary (paper, document size, print size...).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and giving me another perspective on the solution! I will definitely give it a try.

I would be grateful if you could explain what exactly this does:

maxHeight="1.7976931348623157E308" maxWidth="1.7976931348623157E308" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity"

Comment: These sizes are not essential. SceneBuilder sets them when selecting "MAX_VALUE". A leftover fragment of me playing around with your FXML.